# Google Cloud Messaging Shows - 500. Internal server error - When I login to the Google Account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-500

I get the error when I try to open this link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Like this:

[image]

It display the error only when I logged in to my Google Account. If I log out from the Google Account so it does not display the error and simply display the page...

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I can't repro. Could very well be a transient condition, they happen occasionally. I wouldn't worry unless such condition persists for more than just a few hours.

Comment: Its from last a Week.. @DanCornilescu

Comment: Sounds like there could be some trouble related to your account specifically, I'd contact google support.

Comment: I also not able to open this webpage: https://developers.google.com/

Comment: What I do ? How I connect to Google About this ?

Comment: Well, from the GCM support page(which you can't see) - the `google-cloud-messaging` tag here is one of the support channels. Another one is this `form` (if you can get to it): https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support. The `Send Feedback` one won't work since you can't get to the pages...

Comment: Thank you, But link give by you, Its also want the Project ID which I does not remember.